# Remove "almost similar" duplicates

Tags: notepad++

I tried many things but can't sort that out.

I am trying to clean my Emulators Roms game lists.

Here is what it looks like:

```
1943 Kai: Midway Kaisen (Japan) 
1943: Battle of Midway (bootleg, hack of Japan set) 
1943: Midway Kaisen (Japan) 
1943: Midway Kaisen (Japan, Rev B) 
1943: The Battle of Midway (Euro) 
1943: The Battle of Midway (US, Rev C) 
1944: The Loop Master (Japan 000620) 
1944: The Loop Master (USA 000620 Phoenix Edition) (bootleg) 
1944: The Loop Master (USA 000620) 
1945 Part-2 (Chinese hack of Battle Garegga) 
1945k III 
1991 Spikes (Italian bootleg) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (Asia 951207) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (Brazil 951218) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (Hispanic 951218) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (Japan 951207) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (Japan 951225) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (USA 951207 Phoenix Edition) (bootleg) 
19XX: The War Against Destiny (USA 951207)
```

What I need is to keep only one line for each game and delete what's in between the ( ) to get something like this:

```
1943 Kai: Midway Kaisen 
1943: The Battle of Midway
1944: The Loop Master
1945 Part-2
1945k III 
1991 Spikes
19XX: The War Against Destiny
```

If you could help me to trick it I would be really grateful.

Comment: I'd use a regex to trim `(` to end of line, then remove duplicate lines.  That said, this is probably a better fit for SuperUser them SO

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to remove all bracets with their content you can use the search and replace feature of Notepad++. Activate the Regular expression functionality and use the following pattern:

```
\(.*?\)
```

Replace the content with nothing.

[image]

Since there are some unregular spaces in your document the second step would be to remove all double spaces by

- Find what:  (two spaces)
- Replace with:  (one space)

After that you are able to remove all duplicate lines with (thanks to Patrick Artners comment)

- Find what: `\r\n(.*)\r\n\1`
- Replace with: `\r\n\1`

Note that you need to need to execute the replace function multiple times until all duplicates are removed.

Comment: to remove duplicates after that: `\r\n(.*)\r\n\1` and replace with `\1` ?

Comment: Almost perfect @PatrickArtner ... I`ve added a working version to my answer.

Comment: I managed to delete () and double Spaces but the next command won't work : \r\n(.*)\r\n\1

What's wrong ? Thanks again :)

Comment: Replacement is set correctly? ... Maybe the lines are not exactly the same ? (Some spaces left?)

Comment: Thanks for your helped, solved it with Tommaso formula.

Answer (score 0):

Baby steps...

1. Remove the end-line parentheses, which are the reason why similar references are being kept since they provide uniqueness. Using regular expressions, search for `\s*?\(.+$` and replace the matching occurrences with an empty string.
2. In order to remove duplicate rows, since the duplicate rows are immediately after each other, find `^(.*\r?\n)(\1)+` and replace the matching occurrences with `\1`.

Comment: The command ^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$) worked well ! Many Thanks ! :)

My file now look like that :

`
1941: Counter Attack 
1942 
1942h
1943 Kai: Midway Kaisen 
1943: Battle of Midway 
1943: Midway Kaisen 
1943: The Battle of Midway 
1944: The Loop Master 
1945 Part-2 
1945k III 
1991 Spikes 
19XX: The War Against Destiny
`

Comment: I edited my answer since the previous approach showed drawbacks. Try if the new solution works too.